# Determine accuracy of a model in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, modeling

I am currently trying to make some plot showing that GMM is better at modeling data than MNN (multi model normal distribution), but can't make a plot in which both fits are in. Here is my current code:

```
MU1 = [1 2];
SIGMA1 = [2 0; 0 .5];
MU2 = [4 6];
SIGMA2 = [1 0; 0 1];


rng(1); % For reproducibility
X = [mvnrnd(MU1,SIGMA1,1000);
     mvnrnd(MU2,SIGMA2,1000)];

figure;
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),10,'.')


options = statset('Display','final');
gm = fitgmdist(X,2,'Options',options); % GMM fit
G = fitgmdist(X,1) % fit MNN - only 1 component are being  used
gmPDF = @(x,y)pdf(gm,[x y]);
F = @(x,y) pdf(G,[x y])

hold on
%h = ezcontour(gmPDF,[-3 10],[-3 10]);
d = ezcontour(F,[-3 10],[-3 10]);
title('Scatter Plot and PDF Contour')
hold off
%%
close all
```

I am able to see the plots, but can i somehow print the accuracy of both?
Something like number of outliers or something else?

Comment: I can see the scatter plot and the contour. What do you mean by "accuracy"? By the way, the last line "close all" closes the plot window.

Comment: Last line intended.. I was thinking if some value of how well the data fits to model it has fitted to...  Currently it looks like MVN seem to perform better than GMM..

Comment: It is not clear where you are calculating the fit using GMM versus the fit using MNN. Could you add some comments to the code showing that?

Comment: added @ammportal